# I cannot display the data on antd table

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

I have an array whose value are loaded before render from the database, but I don't know why I can't display it on my table.

```
class GetUsers extends Component{
  getUser(){
    var arr = this.props.user;
    var userArray =[];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      userArray.push({
        key: i,
        name: arr[i].full_name,
        phone : arr[i].phone_number,
        email: arr[i].email,
      })
    }
      return userArray
      console.log(userArray)
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.getUserData();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <Table dataSource={this.userArray}>
          <Column
            title="Name"
            dataIndex="name"
            key="name"
          />
          <Column
            title="Phone"
            dataIndex="phone"
            key="phone"
          />

        <Column
          title="Email"
          dataIndex="email"
          key="email"
        />
     </Table>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    user: state.user,
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserData})(GetUsers);
```

So there is array and I can see that I have values in it but I just don't know why I can't display them on the table. It says NO DATA. The titles can only be seen.

Comment: Do you mean  <Table dataSource={this.getUser()}>?

Comment: i tried doing that as well. It gives me error
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, name, phone, email}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: It might be because `this.userArray` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

where's your variable `this.userArray`,and your function `this.getUser` is not use.
is that a slip of the pen?